# Powershell COM ports

Tags: powershell, serial-port

A USB HASP dongle and USB serial converter are recognized by Device Manager but not by Powershell [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()"  on my Win7 nor Win8.1 machines. 
What other way can I indentify my COM ports in Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-WmiObject "win32_serialport"
```

and

```
Get-WmiObject "win32_POTSModem"
```

also display information on COM ports, but specific to device-ports and com-modems. 
Output may give less port names than in [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames() but in win32_POTSModem you can get info of installed and now disconnected devices (like usb-com modems)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  Unfortunately, neither produced a response on either machine. However, in retrying [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames() again I got a COM5 response on the Win7 machine but nothing on the Win8.1

Comment: Further tests on the Win7 and Win8.1 machines have compared the use of  [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames() with Device Manager results. 

     USB Port   [System.IO...   Device Manager USB Serial Converter
Win7    A    COM5            Port_#0001.Hub_#0001
           B       COM5            Port_#0003.Hub_#0001
           C       COM5            Port_#0002.Hub_#0001
Win8.1     D        -              Port_#0003.Hub_#0003
           E        -              Port_#0004.Hub_#0003
           F        -              Port_#0001.Hub_#0004
Powershell gives a result on Win7 but not on Win8.1.
.